# How to extract data from a .docx file including image, table, formula etc?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am doing a task in which i have to extract data from word document mainly images, tables and special texts(formula etc) .

I am able to save image from a word file it is downloaded from web but when i am applying same code to my .docx file than it is giving error.

Code for same is

```
//create file inputstream to read from a binary file
      FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(filename);
      //create office word 2007+ document object to wrap the word file
      XWPFDocument docx=new XWPFDocument(fs);
      //get all images from the document and store them in the list piclist
      List<XWPFPictureData> piclist=docx.getAllPictures();
      //traverse through the list and write each image to a file
      Iterator<XWPFPictureData> iterator=piclist.iterator();
      System.out.println(piclist.size());
      while(iterator.hasNext()){

       XWPFPictureData pic=iterator.next();
       byte[] bytepic=pic.getData();
       int i=0;
       BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytepic));
       //captureimage(imag,i,flag,j);
       if(imag != null)
       {
               ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File("D:/imagefromword"+i+".jpg"));  
       }else{
           System.out.println("imag is empty");
       }
```

It is giving incorrect format error. But I cannot change the doc file.
Secondly for above code if i am having more then one image and when i am saving this than every time it saving save image. Suppose we have 3 images then it will save 3 images but all three will be latest one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from your error.

Answer (score 0):

Without actual error one can only guess.
But there are two POI implementations HWPF and XWPF depending which version of word document your read the old doc one or xml-new-one docx. Typically the format error comes when you try to open the doc using the wrong one. 
Also you need the full poi-ooxml-schemas jar to read more complicated documents.